# Natural Binary Code - finding first n numbers

Tags: python, binary

Outputting/finding first n numbers of Natural Binary Code:

```
import math  
def binary_print(n):
    m = int(math.ceil(math.log(n, 2)))
    for i in range(n):
        b = str(bin(i)[2:])
        print((m - len(b)) * '0' + b)
```

My question is:

Do you know any other way to do this in Python? Maybe faster? Or shorter (less code)?

Comment: Sorry, What exactly is this supposed to output?

Comment: First n natural binary numbers. For example binary_print(3) outputs 00
01
10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928297/all-permutations-of-a-binary-sequence-x-bits-long/4928350#4928350 might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def binary_values(n):
    fmt = "{0:0"+str((n-1).bit_length())+"b}"
    for i in range(n):
        print fmt.format(i)
```

Note: (n-1).bit_length() fixes a fencepost error (otherwise if n is a power of two it prints 1 too many leading zeros).

Might also be able to speed it up a bit more by unrolling a lookup,

```
def binary_values(n):
    fmt = ("{0:0"+str((n-1).bit_length())+"b}").format
    for i in range(n):
        print fmt(i)
```

Comment: Yes, my answer was out by one - fixed now. Your answer is faster, I was going for the one-liner!

Comment: I like both the answers. I'm learning Python by solving small problems like this one and I learned a lot analysing your solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Well this is shorter, not sure about faster:

```
def binary_print(n):
    print '\n'.join('{:0{}b}'.format(x, (n-1).bit_length()) for x in range(n))
```

Example usage:

```
>>> binary_print(6)
000
001
010
011
100
101
```

Comment: My Python 2.6.6 says AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'bit_length'. Is it a feature od Python3?