# N nested for-loops

Tags: algorithm, for-loop

I need to create N nested loops to print all combinations of a binary sequence of length N. Im not sure how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It is likely to be Java. I only need to work out the pseudo code. I can stick it into any language once I have the solution

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928297/all-permutations-of-a-binary-sequence-x-bits-long/4928350#4928350

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Python. I'm not sure what you answer to that question is doing. Are you hard-coding all the possibilities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use recursion.  e.g., in Java

```
public class Foo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Foo().printCombo("", 5);
   }

   void printCombo(String soFar, int len) {
      if (len == 1) {
         System.out.println(soFar+"0");
         System.out.println(soFar+"1");
      }
      else {
         printCombo(soFar+"0", len-1);
         printCombo(soFar+"1", len-1);
      }         
   }
}
```

will print
00000
00001
00010
...
11101
11110
11111

Comment: This might work. I'll try and implement it into my algorithm and get back to you.

Comment: @BluffTrout: It *will* work because recursion is how you solve this problem.

Comment: @BluffTrout  Depending on the criteria you use to determine if it is a feasible solution, you could add a check at the start of printCombo(), e.g. `if (notFeasable(soFar)) return;`

Comment: This has worked great. I have managed to change it to fit what I was looking for. Thanks for everyone's help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Use backtracking instead.
2. Write a program that generates a dynamic program with N loops and then executes it.

Comment: I don't think Backtracking is correct, since that only applies when some solutions are impossible.  I think what you meant was recursion.

Comment: Yes, actually I meant the recursive backtracking. Also you can use backtracking with an empty validation function i.e. accept any generated solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any nested loops for this. You need one recursive function to print a binary value of length N and a for loop to iterate over all numbers [0 .. (2^N)-1].

user949300's solution is also very good, but it might not work in all languages.

Here's my solution(s), the recursive one is approximately twice as slow as the iterative one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef RECURSIVE
void print_bin(int num, int len)
{
   if(len == 0)
   {
      printf("\n");
      return;
   }

   print_bin(num >> 1, len -1);
   putchar((num & 1) + '0');
}
#else
void print_bin(int num, int len)
{
    char str[len+1];
    int i;

    str[len] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
       str[len-1-i] = !!(num & (1 << i)) + '0';
    }

    printf("%s\n", str);
}
#endif

int main()
{
   int len = 24;
   int i;
   int end = 1 << len;

   for (i = 0; i < end ; i++)
   {
      print_bin(i, len);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

(I tried this myself on a Mac printing all binary numbers of length 24 and the terminal froze. But that is probably a poor terminal implementation. :-)

```
$ gcc -O3 binary.c ; time ./a.out > /dev/null ; gcc -O3 -DRECURSIVE binary.c ; time ./a.out > /dev/null 

real        0m1.875s
user        0m1.859s
sys         0m0.008s

real        0m3.327s
user        0m3.310s
sys         0m0.010s
```

Comment: Ouch. Yeah that will probably not work. In terms of the program that I am creating, I need to step through each combination and see if it's a feasible solution to another problem. It doesn't neccessarily, need to compute all combinations at once.

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with the algorithm as such but with Terminal.app's ability to handle the history.

Comment: For large N my algorithm might run out of memory.

Comment: So for large N do it more explicitly via a single for-next loop and, in Java, Integer.toString(theValue, 2);.  Same idea as [presented here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928297/all-permutations-of-a-binary-sequence-x-bits-long/4928336#4928336)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need recursion or n nested for-loops to solve this problem. It would be easy to handle this using bit manipulation.

In C++, as an example:

```
for(int i=0;i<(1<<n);i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    if(i&(1<<j))
      printf("1");
    else
      printf("0");
  printf("\n");
}
```