# Python: Getting binary permutations, but controlling loop flow

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

For starters, I read this: [all permutations of a binary sequence x bits long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928297/all-permutations-of-a-binary-sequence-x-bits-long)

This is similar to what I want, but I don't want to generate all permutations in advance. What I want is more of a generator that I can step through and stop whenever I want (for efficiency reasons, I have cutoff conditions where I want to halt).

I was wondering if there is an elegant way to do this Python. The answers to the question above all involved ".join"s, but I don't think that will work here. I assume I need to use itertools.

Any ideas?

Comment: Python has _very_ elegant generators. Just google "python generator".

Comment: @alexis This is interesting: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators. However, I have never worked with generators before, do you mind showing me how it would work in my case?

Comment: [The python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) is the place to start. But see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you like the solution in the answer you link to, here's the generator version:

```
for pattern in ("".join(seq) for seq in itertools.product("01", repeat=3)):
    ...
```

Using parens instead of square brackets `[ ... ]` gives you a generator that creates the values on demand.

It's easy to turn almost any function into generator; see [the python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) for the details.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Now I know about generators, they seem very handy.